# After Bitlocker Decrypt Disk is Write Protected

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, encryption, bitlocker

I have an internal HDD that was previously a Win7 boot disk and was encrypted with Bitlocker.  I replaced the old computer with a new one with a new HDD.  I moved the old Bitlocker encrypted HDD to the new system and decrypted it.  Now the HDD is write protected.  Bitlocker even gave a message after decryption saying that the HDD would be write protected.  How can I remove the write protected status short of reformatting the disk (which I don't want to do)?

I have changed the Group Policy for Bitlocker drives, and I have used diskpart to remove the attribute on both the HDD as a whole and on the partition.  Nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Disabling group policy in Windows doesn't change anything. I resolved following:

1. Open Windows registry (`regedit`)
2. Navigate to

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Policies\Microsoft\FVE
   ```
3. Change value of `FDVDenyWriteAccess` to "0".
4. Restart computer, it should work as expected.